# ACE Editor Line Endings Set To Windows Format

Tags: webkit, ace-editor

Is there a way to set line endings to windows? Which are ^M if i'm not mistaken

I'm sending my ACE to a private API which I cannot control, this expects a format with windows line endings.

```
Editor = ace.edit("e"); 
ValueSentToServer = Editor.getValue();
```

Is what i am using to get the value.

When doing an ajax call to get a file source I'm seeing

```
↵
```

As the line ending tags in WebKit console.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use `editor.session.setNewLineMode("windows")`

but if you submit it with form chances are line endings will be converted by browser automatically. See https://github.com/ajaxorg/ace/issues/1515#issuecomment-20971401 and http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/interact/forms.html#h-17.13.4

Answer (score 1):

What language are you coding? In Java:

Try something like:

```
v = editor.getValue();
v = v.replace( "\n", "\r\n");
// send V to server
```

You could very well improve your variable naming. Major entities/ objects should have names -- 'e' should be 'editor', for example.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, greatly appreciated.
XML code in the editor being passed to Java to be saved.

Comment: Sending V to the server results in the next load having no line breaks still :S

Comment: Have you checked to see the \n is actually being found & replaced?  Make sure it is, and check that the outgoing payload is correct for what the server wants. (Try logging string-lengths before & after replacement, and checking that a known constant payload is processed as you expect.)